# Oozie property file value not reading from spark

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have a property file in oozie and getting value from shell script like below:

```
filter_cond = record = 'n' and name = 'abc' and  age = '14'
```

in Shell script

```
 val cond = ${getproperty filter_cond}
```

It's not reading this entire value, It's read till filter_cond=record

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i removed symbol(=) and used like command because symbol(=) is reserved key work for delimiter.

Below one works fine.

filter_cond="record like 'n' and name like 'abc' and age like '14'"

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to enclose the whole value of the variable in double quotes like this:

```
filter_cond="record='n' and name='abc' and age='14'"
```

Comment: I't not working,I tried already it takes null value if you use double quotes

Comment: if you remove = it's wokring fine but i want to add this filter cond